Why can we interpret forces on particles as components of a smooth convector field in the n-Body problem?
I'm trying to understand Example 22.18 (The $n$-Body Problem) in John Lee's Smooth Manifolds textbook. I'm confused by the step where the forces in Newton's second law [Eq. (22.12)] are interpreted as components of a smooth covector field on the (collision-less) coordinate space. (The smooth part makes sense to me but the covector field does not.)
Here's the setup: The evolution of $n$ particles in $\mathbb{R}^3$ over time is represented by a curve in $\mathbb{R}^{3n}$: $q(t) = (q_1^1(t), q_1^2(t), q_1^3(t), \ldots, q_n^1(t), q_n^2(t), q_n^3(t))$. We restriction our attention to the open subset $Q$ of $\mathbb{R}^3$ that has no particle collisions. We next invoke some classical mechanics. The net force on the $k$-th particle is $\mathbf{F}=(F_k^1(q), F_k^2(q), F_k^3(q))$. Particle $k$ has mass $m_k$ so Newton's second law yields
$$m_k \ddot{q}_k^1(t) = F_k^1(q(t)),\\
m_k \ddot{q}_k^2(t) = F_k^2(q(t)),\\
m_k \ddot{q}_k^3(t) = F_k^3(q(t)).$$
This can be rewritten more compactly by relabeling the position and forces as $q(t) = (q^1(t), \ldots, q^{3n}(t))$ and $F(q) = (F_1(q), \ldots, F_{3n}(q))$, respectively. Let $M= (M_{ij}$ denote the $3n\times 3n$ diagonal matrix with entries $(m_1, m_1, m_1, m_2, m_2, m_2, \ldots, m_n, m_n, m_n)$. The set of equations above---given by Newton's second law---can be rewritten as
$$ M_{ij} \ddot{q}^j(t) = F_i(q(t)).$$
Lee then states that $F(q) = (F_1(q), \ldots, F_{3n}(q))$ can be interpreted as components of a smooth covector field on $Q$.
Why should these be components of a covector field? Why not components of a vector field? Is this just an interpretation that is made because things work out nicely or is there some intuition I'm missing?

Force is the time derivative of momentum. Why the latter is a covector is explained with various levels of sophistication here and here.
